# Definition of List in Agda

Tags: types, functional-programming, agda, algebraic-data-types, gadt

On page 4 of [*Dependently Typed Programming in Agda*](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~ulfn/papers/afp08/tutorial.pdf), `List` is defined as follows

```
infixr 40 _::_
data List (A : Set) : Set where
  [] : List A
  _::_ : A -> List A -> List A
```

I have difficulties wrapping my head around the last line. I've learned some Haskell a while ago, so I am familiar with the *cons* operator.

So, either you have an empty list, which is of type `List A`, or you create a new value with function `::` of type `A -> List A -> List A`, which takes some element of type `A` and a list of type `A` and returns a new list?

This seems to be the intuition, but this does not map to the concept of recursive data type definitions as I know it (from haskell), e.g.

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

**Question** So what kind of type is this? What concepts of Agda are involved here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two syntaxes to define data types in Haskell and Agda.

Simple one:

```
data List a = Nil | a :# List a
```

And more expressive one (in Haskell it is used to define [GADTs](https://wiki.haskell.org/Generalised_algebraic_datatype)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data List a where
    Nil :: List a
    (:#) :: a -> List a -> List a
```

Comment: I still don't see how this helps me to understand the concepts involved in Agda.

Comment: the concept is the same (recursive datatype), just different syntax (with explicit types of constructors).

Comment: So the Agda code contains no language-specific concepts, i.e. dependent types? `List` is just a straightforward GADT?

Comment: yep, there are no dependent types in this example